# How can i override core api interface in my custom module

Tags: interface

i am trying to override model and interface of core api in to my custom module for adding new data but i am not able to override interface to add that data contract.

Comment: Can you write more with code?

Comment: Can you please provide the solution that worked for you.!!

Comment: @nikunj 
Could you please help me on this question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file

Answer (score 0):

Classes in PHP can implement many interfaces at once. Your best bet is to write your own interface which adds the methods you require, then implement the models you want to implement the interfaces you need.

**The interface**

```
interface MyCustomManagementInterface
{
    public myMethod();
}
```

**The Class**

```
class MyCustomClass implements \Magento\Framework\Some\Interface,
    MyCustomManagementInterface
{
}
```

Comment: How can I override core Interface and Mode. Please let me know ? 
Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface.php Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value.php

Comment: You can't override an interface. The best you can do is create an interface that inherits from the core interface and then use preferences in di.xml to provide your custom class that extends the core class and implements your custom interface.

Comment: Thank you. 
Please below path have preference and i have to add custom code in intarface and model as well 
magento2/vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/di.xml
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value" />

Give me example for di.xml file

Comment: Could you please help me on this question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file